# React Native Animated: TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined, js engine: hermes

Tags: react-native, settimeout, react-animated

I am running a very basic app right now as it is in the very beginning of development, so I do not believe this to be an issue of conflicting dependencies.
I am using React Native Animated views and setTimeout as a way to trigger a view box fading into the screen 1.5 seconds after the screen has been opened. To do that, I have a `useEffect` that looks as follows...

```
 useEffect(() => {
    if (!fadeStarted){
        setTimeout(fadeIn(), 1500)
        setFadeStarted(true)
    } 
 }, [])
```

And the animated view and `fadeIn` method look as follows...

```
const fadeIn = () => {
    if (fadeStarted){
        return null
    }
    Animated.timing(fade, {
        toValue: 1,
        duration: 4000,
        useNativeDriver: true
    }).start();
};


<Animated.View style={{opacity: fade, marginTop: 55, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
    <Text style={{fontFamily: 'Gilroy-ExtraBold', color: "#28DE19", fontSize: 40, textAlign: 'center'}}>Kingdom of William</Text>
    <Text style={{fontFamily: 'Gilroy-SemiBold', color: "#28DE19", fontSize: 20, textAlign: 'center'}}>(Get it?)</Text>
</Animated.View>
```

The fade-in works, but once 1.5 seconds pass by, setTimeout seems to try to call itself again, but it cannot call fadein while its already fading in I believe, which returns this error:
`React Native Animated: TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined, js engine: hermes`

As you can see, I have a boolean state, `fadeStarted` to prevent the `setTimeout` from being hit again, but I suppose that's not how setTimeout works. However, having it return null right away inside of fadeIn I thought would do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the two spots I added the guard with `fadeStarted` were the wrong two. I changed the useEffect to look like this instead, and it worked

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("hit inside of useEffect")
    if (!fadeStarted){
        setTimeout(function(){
            if (fadeStarted){
                return null
            }
            fadeIn()
        }, 1500)
        setFadeStarted(true)
    } 
}, [])
```